# Holographic magnification and the requirement of single wavelength coherent reference wave

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, microscopy, hologram

**How is holographic magnification for different wavelength reference beams consistent with the requirement of illuminating the hologram with light with wavelength same as the reference beam?**

1. If we need to reconstruct the object wave, we are required to illuminate the hologram with the reference wave used to record it.
2. By the principle of holographic magnification, we can magnify the image if we illuminate the hologram with light of wavelength greater than the reference wave.

How can both of these statements be consistent with each other? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is not correct.  Illumination with a replica of the original reference wave is only necessary if you want to reconstruct the original object beam exactly.

The second statement is correct.  However, it may be important to note that distortions occur except under very restrictive conditions.

A hologram is basically a superposition of a lot of diffraction gratings, and each of those component diffraction gratings redirects light independently.  At least for a thin grating, each wavelength of light is diffracted through an angle that depends on the wavelength.  See [http://nli-ltd.com/publications/graphical_method.php ] for an easy way to graphically compute the diffraction angle vs incidence angle and wavelength.